# Searching for Field in ODBC Machine Data Sources - MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Yesterday I had to run a query in MS Access 2010.  One field I needed was not in the tables I usually use (already linked through the ODBC Database) and I didn't know what table it was a part (there are several hundred tables in the Machine Data Sources).  Aside from manually importing all the tables and looking in each one for this field is there a way I can search for a field without knowing the table either 1. without importing any tables from the ODBC Databases, or if not 2. importing a handful of possible tables and searching once those tables have been linked into my active MS Access 2010 session?

Answer (score 0):

Install [Access Dependency Checker](http://www.accessdependencychecker.com/), link all tables and search for column name (enable checkbox for search in linked tables)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a Function using ADO schema's.

Try this function in a standard module:

```
    Function ListTablesContainingField(SelectFieldName) As String

       Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
       Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
       Dim strTempList As String           

       Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

      'Get names of all tables that have a column called <SelectFieldName>
       Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, _
       Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, SelectFieldName))

      'List the tables that have been selected
       While Not rs.EOF
          'Exclude MS system tables
           If Left(rs!Table_Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
               strTempList = strTempList & "," & rs!Table_Name
           End If
           rs.MoveNext
       Wend

       ListTablesContainingField = Mid(strTempList, 2)


       rs.Close
       Set cn = Nothing

   End Function
```

Comment: Is this pre-link when the tables only reside in the ODBC Database or post when they are linked into the Access session?